# Displaying row numbers

Tags: php, pagination

So I wanna display the row number (ranking) before every record.
Now the code below shows correct on the first page. 1 thru 25, but then I go the second page then a 6 is added before the row number. Should be 26 thru 50 but instead it's 626 thru 650. Would be correct if the number 6 werent there. And so it goes on, on page 3 its 1251 thru 1275 (should be 51 thru 75). Whats wrong here?

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
$perPage = 25;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $perPage;

$query "SELECT name, exp FROM people ORDER BY exp DESC LIMIT $offset, $perPage";


<? $i = (($perPage * $offset) +1); foreach($db->query($query) as $row): ?>
Ranking: <?=$i?>
Name: <?=$row['name']?>

<? $i++; endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$i` calculation is wrong. You have already used `$perPage` in offset calculation. Why using it again?

```
$i = (($perPage * $offset) +1);
```

should be

```
$i = $offset + 1;
```

**[Demonstration for fun](http://codepad.org/kssaOoJ2)**